# Tensorflow Keras CuDNN LSTM layers do not support Masking

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a NER using TF keras, when I do zero padding to get the batches to same length and then add a tf.keras.layers.Masking() layer to mask the padding, the error I get is that CuDNNLSTM does not support Masking.

My Tensorflow-gpu version is 1.11,  Cuda 9.0, CudNN 7.3.1.

I currently do have the version working where I just group same length samples into each batch to avoid padding, I would like to know if we should just not pad from now on or if CuDNN LSTM will support masking paddings in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found this

> CuDNN RNNs cannot be used with masking for the time being, and likely never will be. It would need to be implemented at the CuDNN level.

see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8620)

Comment: Tensorflow 1.12.1 has support has landed for extended cuDNN-RNN (supporting variable sequences) ops. This should enable masking to be implemented in Keras, but this does not seem to have happened yet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23269#issuecomment-531026097